# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set. JAVAFX cant open window

Tags: javafx, set, location, illegalstateexception

im trying to build a client-server program with javaFX.
this is my project structure:
[image: project structure]

this is my code for opening the window in LoginController:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxml/login.fxml"));
        System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/fxml/login.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("EasyFit login");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

the println gives null for some reason....

also i dont use maven or gradle. just plain eclipse ide.

iv seen other posts but nothing works for me and i dont know what im doing wrong...

and this is the error message i get:

```
null
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1082)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2459)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at client.gui.controllers.LoginController.start(LoginController.java:105)
    at client.ClientUI.start(ClientUI.java:29)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application client.ClientUI
```

i tried using / or ../ or no / or /full/path but nothing works.

Comment: *"i tried using / or ../ or no / or /full/path but nothing works."* Using a leading `/` with the fully qualified resource name, i.e. `"/client/gui/fxml/login.fxml"` should work. If it doesn't, you need to check your build folder or jar file to see if the FXML is included in the expected location.

Comment: _i tried using / or ../ or no / or /full/path_ random experimenting is rarely a good idea: instead, study the api doc of (all) methods you are using to learn its usage, in particual which parameter in which format the method expect :)